# BATCH IF EXIST anything is always true, even for an empty directory

Tags: batch-file

Here's my problem. I need to check either some directory contains another random-named directory, or simply contains anything, or it's empty.

Simple IF EXIST test returns true even if the tested directory is empty:

```
C:\Users\user>dir /B .\a

C:\Users\user>if exist .\a\* echo true
true
```

I understand that's because of theese lines:

```
C:\Users\user>dir /A:D .\a\ |findstr "<DIR>"
2014-03-12  11:26    <DIR>          .
2014-03-12  11:26    <DIR>          ..
```

which are making the directory technicaly not-empty, thus I can't use this method to determine if the directory contains another one or not.

Here I ran out of ideas.
So, is there a simple way to test if a directory contains another one without knowing its name?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find a really simple solution, but this isn't too bad.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set empty=1
for /d %%F in (.\a\*) do set "empty="
if defined empty (
  echo .\a does NOT contain another folder
) else (
  echo .\a contains another folder
)
```

Probably not needed, but it could be made a bit more efficient with the addition of a GOTO

```
@echo off
setlocal
set empty=1
for /d %%F in (.\a\*) do set "empty="&goto :break
:break
if defined empty (
  echo .\a does NOT contain another folder
) else (
  echo .\a contains another folder
)
```

---

**EDIT**

I like the [r3ap3r approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22350594/1012053). Below is a list of various useful tests based on that.

Test if folder exists:

```
if exist .\a\ (echo folder exists) else echo folder does not exist
```

Test if existing folder contains any files:

```
dir /b /a-d .\a\*|findstr . >nul&&echo folder contains files||echo folder does not contain files
```

Test if existing folder contains folders:

```
dir /b /ad .\a\*|findstr . >nul&&echo folder contains folders||echo folder does not contain folders
```

Test if existing folder is empty (no files or folders):

```
dir /b /a .\a\*|findstr . >nul&&echo folder is not empty||echo folder is empty
```

Comment: Thanks you guys!

r3ap3r's one-liner is beautiful but dbenham's method works with directories.

Thanks again!

Comment: @user3410161 - I agree, r3ap34's one liner is elegant. It can easily be adpated to support looking for folders. See my comment to his question, as well as my edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@echo off
( dir /b /a "C:\test\" | findstr . ) > nul && (
  echo Not Empty
) || ( echo Empty )
```

Comment: +1, The OP is is a bit unclear, but I think (s)he wants to know if the folder contains another folder. Use of `dir /b /ad` will work perfectly for that.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "emptydir=u:\q22349927"
MD %emptydir%
ECHO made an empty directory
DIR /b %emptydir%|FIND /v "" >nul 
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (ECHO %emptydir% is empty) ELSE (ECHO %emptydir% is NOT empty)
ECHO add a directory
MD %emptydir%\nolongerempty
DIR /b %emptydir%|FIND /v "" >nul
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (ECHO %emptydir% is empty) ELSE (ECHO %emptydir% is NOT empty)
ECHO add a file
dir>%emptydir%\file.txt
DIR /b %emptydir%|FIND /v "" >nul
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (ECHO %emptydir% is empty) ELSE (ECHO %emptydir% is NOT empty)
ECHO remove the directory - just the file remains
RD %emptydir%\nolongerempty
DIR /b %emptydir%|FIND /v "" >nul
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (ECHO %emptydir% is empty) ELSE (ECHO %emptydir% is NOT empty)
ECHO remove the file - nothing remains
DEL %emptydir%\file.txt
DIR /b %emptydir%|FIND /v "" >nul
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (ECHO %emptydir% is empty) ELSE (ECHO %emptydir% is NOT empty)
RD %emptydir%

GOTO :EOF
```

Here's a demo to show you how...